# query to get result object with only one object inside an array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mean-stack, mongoose-schema

i need to implement an online survey MEAN stack app. i need to get an document from a collection with only on object inside `inv_users` array. my document is like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5a431d73fcaf01ec6274ecbc",
        "name": "Patient Satisfaction survey",
        "company_id": "5a432162fcaf01ec6274ec89",
        "start_datetime": "2017-12-11T06:57:44.650Z",
        "end_datetime": "2018-12-11T06:57:44.650Z",
        "logo": "",
        "header_title": "Patient satisfaction Survey",
        "footer_title": "powered by team",
        "img_read_code": "",
        "mail_responded": true,
        "survey_complete": true,
        "inv_users": [
            {
                "email": "jooshipp@gmail.com",
                "ip": "192.168.1.17",
                "latitude": 39.02,
                "longitude": -119.47,
                "survey_completed": false,
                "mail_responsed": false,
                "mail_viewed": true,
                "cmp_user_id": "5a432162fcaf01ec6274ecc0"
            },
            {
                "email": "jamal@gmail.com",
                "ip": "192.168.1.17",
                "latitude": 39.02,
                "longitude": -119.47,
                "survey_completed": false,
                "mail_responsed": false,
                "mail_viewed": true,
                "cmp_user_id": "5a432162fcaf01ec6274ecc8"
            }
        ],
        "answers": [
            {
                "answer": "Satisfied",
                "date_time": "2017-03-24T12:15:12.000Z",
                "ip": "192.168.1.17",
                "latitude": 42.05,
                "longitude": -119.47,
                "global_user_id": "5a431dbafcaf01ec6274ecc0",
                "cmp_user_id": ""
            }
        ],
        "questions": [
            {
                "question": "Are you satisfied with the appearance",
                "ans_type": "Multiple choice",
                "options": [
                    "No",
                    "Satisfied",
                    "a little",
                    "Very Satisfied"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "is_footer": true,
        "is_header": true,
        "display_type": {
            "ui": "single",
            "randamization": true,
            "pageno": true,
            "skip": true,
            "randomization": false
        },
        "category": {
            "id": "5a4167b5aa77271cb7f228ed",
            "name": "Collect Feedback"
        }
    }
]
```

what my result should look is like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5a431d73fcaf01ec6274ecbc",
        "name": "Patient Satisfaction survey",
        "company_id": "5a432162fcaf01ec6274ec89",
        "start_datetime": "2017-12-11T06:57:44.650Z",
        "end_datetime": "2018-12-11T06:57:44.650Z",
        "logo": "",
        "header_title": "Patient satisfaction Survey",
        "footer_title": "powered by team",
        "img_read_code": "",
        "mail_responded": true,
        "survey_complete": true,
        "inv_users": [
            {
                "email": "jooshipp@gmail.com",
                "ip": "192.168.1.17",
                "latitude": 39.02,
                "longitude": -119.47,
                "survey_completed": false,
                "mail_responsed": false,
                "mail_viewed": true,
                "cmp_user_id": "5a432162fcaf01ec6274ecc0"
            }
        ],
        "answers": [
            {
                "answer": "Satisfied",
                "date_time": "2017-03-24T12:15:12.000Z",
                "ip": "192.168.1.17",
                "latitude": 42.05,
                "longitude": -119.47,
                "global_user_id": "5a431dbafcaf01ec6274ecc0",
                "cmp_user_id": ""
            }
        ],
        "questions": [
            {
                "question": "Are you satisfied with the appearance",
                "ans_type": "Multiple choice",
                "options": [
                    "No",
                    "Satisfied",
                    "a little",
                    "Very Satisfied"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "is_footer": true,
        "is_header": true,
        "display_type": {
            "ui": "single",
            "randamization": true,
            "pageno": true,
            "skip": true,
            "randomization": false
        },
        "category": {
            "id": "5a4167b5aa77271cb7f228ed",
            "name": "Collect Feedback"
        }
    }
]
```

i've already written the mongoose query like this:

```
Survey.find({"_id":req.params.id, "start_datetime": {"$lte": new Date()},"end_datetime": {"$gt": new Date()},inv_users:1, inv_users:{$elemMatch : {  cmp_user_id:user_id}}}, function(err,survey){

            if(survey){
                res.json(survey);
            }
            else if(!survey){

                res.json({
                    status:0,
                    message: "Survey doesn't exist!"
                })  
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed match with projection

```
inv_users:1
```

This in match means match only inv_users whose value is 1. (your intentions might be for project but with output you have asked contradicts this projection)

also,

> The $elemMatch operator limits the contents of an  field from the query results to contain only the first element matching the $elemMatch condition.

This should work in your case

```
Survey.find({
    "_id"           : req.params.id,
    "start_datetime": {"$lte": new Date()},
    "end_datetime"  : {"$gt": new Date()},
    inv_users       : {
        $elemMatch: {
            cmp_user_id: user_id
        }
    }
},
function (err, survey) {
    if (survey) {
        res.json(survey);
    }
    else if (!survey) {
        res.json({
            status : 0,
            message: "Survey doesn't exist!"
        })
    }
});
```